# ASP.NET MVC LINQ GroupBy differs from SQL Server GroupBy?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

Linq rookie here.

I have SQL Server DB where all the raw data for welders coming from. 
There are 17 welders based on their IDs by numbers. They have their percentage KPI for each day (multiple tasks per day) on 1 shift.

I have data like

```
Welder ID        KPI        Date
480              80         2020-04-01
94               60         2020-04-01
480              65         2020-04-02
94               78         2020-04-02
480              95         2020-04-03
94               90         2020-04-03

Expecting 
Welder ID        AvgKPI
480              80
94               76
```

This can be done easily in SQL, image here => https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvEaW.jpg
The upper result table of the first select is from "raw" basic table and the
lower result table is what is just expected in Linq but not in SQL.

I have a report page (ASP.NET MVC5 .NET Framework)
Controller

```
public ActionResult Records(DateTime? start, DateTime? end, string search = "")
if (start == null)
            {
                start = new DateTime(2019, 01, 02);
            }
            if (end == null)
            {
                end = new DateTime();
                end = DateTime.Now;
            };

SiempelLinkedServerEntities db = new SiempelLinkedServerEntities();
            List<ChecksSovaSiempelZak> chartData = db.ChecksSovaSiempelZaks
                                                                                  //base code generating the full list based on parameters 
                .Where(x => x.welderID.Contains(search))                         //  with DateTime? start, DateTime? end, string search=""
                .Where(t => t.Date >= start & t.Date <= end)
                .ToList();



            var dataSet = chartData.Select(k => new { k.welderID, k.welderKPI })
                                    .Distinct()
                                    .GroupBy(x => new { x.welderID}, (key, group) => new
                                    {
                                        IDwelder = key.welderID,
                                        KPIwelder = group.Average(x=>x.welderKPI)
                                    }).ToList();

            var welders = dataSet.Select(x => x.IDwelder);
            var weldersKPI = chartData.Select(x => x.KPIwelder);



            ViewBag.welders = welders;
            ViewBag.weldersKPI = weldersKPI;
```

There's a form with 3 filters, the DateTime start and end parameters return predefined values. Another filter is made for string search for specific person. Not sure if my backend approach is correct.
The expectation is that if there's not set any specific person (search string) return all rows based on datetime parameters as predefined. Those data are going to viewbag cuz of the barchart.
The chart is not showing the average value at all. 
Report page here => https://i.stack.imgur.com/YP7aj.jpg 
The left side of the page is good and correct. Showing the list of specific person, or persons in selected period. How to correct the controller to pass data to Viewbag as expected in SQL Server? 
The average values are dynamic (selected period from datetime parameters).

In short, I want to pass data to chart like X axis = list of welderID, and Y axis = list of Average value for each welder based on selected period.

Any advice is more than welcome.
Sry for my english if something is stated bad

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, I think that you would like to change this line

```
            var weldersKPI = chartData.Select(x => x.KPIwelder);
```

to `var weldersKPI = dataSet.Select(x => x.KPIwelder);`

Comment: I have changed as you mentioned but still gives same result. But good point.Thx

Answer (score 0):

As the whole database and the database model is not any kind of my business, I noticed there are no primary and foreign keys set in the tables that I'm using in the statements.
By adding .AsNoTracking() solved the problem!

```
SiempelLinkedServerEntities db = new SiempelLinkedServerEntities();
            List<ChecksSovaSiempelZak> chartData = db.ChecksSovaSiempelZaks
                .AsNoTracking()                                                            
                .Where(x => x.welderID.Contains(search))                         
                .Where(t => t.Date >= start & t.Date <= end)
                .ToList();
```